# Configuration of reusable bundles in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony totally confused in configuring a custom reusable bundle I'm writing. I've given the description of my problem in the beginning and all the questions are in the end of the question.

I need to inject a configured `GuzzleHttp\Client` instance into a service living in the bundle. Here is the config of the bundle:

```
parameters:
    acl_agent.endpoint: ''

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    GuzzleHttp\Client:
        arguments:
            - [base_uri: '%acl_agent.endpoint%']

    CustomBundle\Service:
        arguments:
            $client: '@GuzzleHttp\Client'
```

The `acl_agent.endpoint` param is supposed to be configured at the host application's scope, therefore I impose it to the user via the `Configuration` class:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acl_agent');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('endpoint')
                    ->example('https://api-gate/service/acl')
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

The user defines the `endpoint` in the host app's config (`app/config/config.yml`) like this:

```
acl_agent:
    endpoint: 'http://api-gate/services/acl'
```

Finally, I assign the user-defined `endpoint` to the `acl_agent.endpoint` parameter in the `Extension::load` method:

```
class AclAgentExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config')
        );

        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $container->setParameter('acl_agent.endpoint', $config['endpoint']);
    }
}
```

After all this, I end up with the empty `GuzzleHttp\Client` config:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [base_uri] => 
        )

)
```

I have a few questions:

1. How to instantiate and configure `GuzzleHttp\Client` by the Symfony way for passing further to a custom service?
2. Do I at all need this `parameters` section with the `acl_agent.endpoint` key in my bundle's `Resources/config/services.yml` parameter or I should use it from the host app's config directly somehow?
3. Why woud I declare a `parameters` section in the bundle's `Resources/config/services.yml` if I can take all the params from the host app's config, as long as they are described in `Configuration::getConfigTreeBuilder` forcing the users of the bundle to define them?
4. What's the connection between the host app's scope params imposed by `Configuration::getConfigTreeBuilder` and the params from the `parameters` section defined in the bundle's config, if any?
5. What's the purpose of the `Extension::load` method and what am I likely to do in it? As far as I've been able to understand, it allows to configure my services more flexibly then I could have done in `Resources/config/services.yml`, I might be missing something.

Gosh, Symfony needs a better documentation.

**UPDATE 11/11/17**

I've figured out that an older version of the cached container was used in the tests, the changes made to the bundle weren't reflected in the construction of the services, therefore the `base_uri` param was empty. As far as I've understood, Symfony automatically detects changes in the app-scope configs and rebuild the cache and I have to manually rebuild it executing the command `php bin/console cache:clear --env=test` when a bundle changes. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

> How to instantiate and configure GuzzleHttp\Client by the Symfony way for passing further to a custom service?

You need initiate client as service in config.yml like this:

```
guzzle:
  logging: true
  clients:
      your_client:
          base_url: "https://your_client_endpoint.com"
          options:
              headers:
                  Accept: "application/json"
              timeout: 3
```

After that, You can inject this client into your service via DI

```
services:
  name_of_service:
    class: path_to_your_service
    arguments: ['@guzzle.your_client']
```

> Do I at all need this parameters section with the acl_agent.endpoint key in my bundle's Resources/config/services.yml parameter or I should use it from the host app's config directly somehow?

Yes, you can, it will look like:

```
parameters:
  your_parameter: 'bla_bla_bla'

services:
  name_of_service:
    class: path_to_your_service
    arguments: ['@guzzle.your_client', '%your_parameter%']
```

For passing parameters from your config.yml file to service, you can use two ways, the first one is Dependency Injection, please look this link
[Symfony Dependency injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html), and a second one (but it is a bad idea and do not use it) - inject callback function into your service.

Comment: I am wondering if the passed guzzle client through DI in my service is a Singleton ? Or if is a new instance in every call of my service which is using guzzle client for a http request. My symfony app is version 3.2 and i have already read that all symfony services are by default shared.

Comment: As I remember from 3.4 changed  "Services are private by default". You can read about it here - https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default. About the lifecycle of each current call - need to investigate. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html